Horror movie with supernatural phone calls
All I remember from this movie is a scene in which a kid answers a call (I think it might from be a toy red phone that is inside a closet and it glows, or something like that) and talks to someone (I belive the kid thinks it is his missing father), and while they talk we see a knife starting to hover and going to kill the kid's mother. When the kid hangs up the phone the knife falls to the floor. The mother never noticed it.
I've seen it in television during the early 90's, most likely a USA film.

The film you're looking for is Joey 1985

When Joey's dad dies Joey is starting to act strange. He's got psychic powers. He can talk to him on the phone! His red toy telephone! But what he doesn't know is that he is not talking to his dad. He is talking to an evil dummy and the evil dummy is starting to make Joey's world a living nightmare.

Here is the trailer where you can see the Red phone and floating knife scene:




Wow, who wrote that IMDB summary? "He is talking to an evil dummy!" Classic.
